# How to prevent blur from CSS transform?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I have some issues using CSS's zooming capability. Whenever I zoom in on an element it gets a little blurry even though it's not an image, just a simple text element.

I'm using Hover.css's code to make grow a div inside my code. But as you can see at Hover.css if you hover your mouse on 'Grow' it gets a bit blurry too.

http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

**CSS Code:**

```
.hvr-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
}
.hvr-grow:hover, .hvr-grow:focus, .hvr-grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

How is that possible to grow the element like this above example, but make everything sharp as before?

Comment: Have you tried font smoothing? -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can increase the size of the element and give it scale less than 1 such .5, then extend scale to 1 (no more than 1) on `hover` / `focus` / `active` or any event , so if you want to increase scale zoom you should increase the element size not the scale to prevent blurry effect.
https://jsfiddle.net/qb2Lhtz9/11/

```css
.hvr-grow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: scale(.5) translateZ(0) translateX(-10%) translateY(-10%);
  font-size: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 400ms;
  transition: transform 400ms;
}
.hvr-grow:hover, .hvr-grow:focus, .hvr-grow:active {
   transform: scale(1)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hvr-grow">Grow</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered making the element scaled smaller by default. Then scale it to 1 when hovered/active?

CSS

```
.hvr-grow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;

  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.hvr-grow:hover, .hvr-grow:focus, .hvr-grow:active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and then the smaller scaled elements are blurry, which is worse than before. Also this wouldn't be good because the main element would be smaller initially this way.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, as suggested here, you first make element as big as on hover, then scale it down to initial size like `transform: scale(.5, .5);` and then on hover switch scale to `transform: scale(1, 1);`

You need to remove `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;` and add perspective(1px) to scale like this `-webkit-transform: perspective(1px) scale(1.1);
  transform: perspective(1px) scale(1.1);` this seems to fix blur in chrome. Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/qb2Lhtz9/9/ it is not perfect, but I hope it can help..